# Django models and primary-foreign key relationships

Tags: python, sql, django-models

I'm writing a Django app that uses existing legacy data combined with a remapping of tables and relationships.  I've been given a table containing the primary-foreign key relationships between the tables, but am having trouble understanding how to adapt it to Django models.

For example, a table `country_metrics` is defined as

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ContractNum | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| fips        | varchar(5)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| metric_id   | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| time_id     | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| value       | decimal(12,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| eff_date    | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| exp_date    | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and I've been given a relationship mapping of

```
ContractNum primary key, foreign key references table contracts
fips        primary key, foreign key references table country
metric_id   primary key, foreign key references table metrics
time_id     primary key, foreign key references table time
```

Its been modeled in the class

```
class ContractCountyMetrics(models.Model):
  contractnum = models.CharField(max_length=10L, db_column='ContractNum', primary_key = true) # Field name made lowercase.
  fips = models.CharField(max_length=5L)
  metric_id = models.IntegerField()
  time_id = models.IntegerField()
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=3)
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  contractKey = models.ForeignKey(Contracts)
  fipsKey = models.ForeignKey(Counties)
  metricKey = models.ForeignKey(Metrics)
  timeKey = models.ForeignKey(Time)
  class Meta:
      db_table = 'txn_contract_county_metrics'
      unique_together("contractKey", "fipsKey", "metricKey", "timeKey")
```

From what I read, `unique_together`basically simulates a composite key and allows more than one field to have primary key functionality.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: i've implemented basic support for virtual Composite Keys. No database modifications are required stackoverflow.com/a/65404017/46548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I read, `unique_together` basically simulates a composite
>   key and allows more than one field to have primary key functionality.
>   Am I on the right track?

Not quite. It just adds a composite `UNIQUE KEY` to the specified fields, and only really has any effect during the creation of the table, which won't apply if you're using Django to access a legacy table. There's still no support for composite `PRIMARY KEY`s in Django (see [bug #373](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373)).

Unfortunately, this probably means that you won't be able to use Django with a legacy table which has a composite `PRIMARY KEY`, without modifying the table to include a Django-compatible `PRIMARY KEY`, i.e. a key on a single, unique, field.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968205/how-to-use-django-with-legacy-readonly-database-tables-with-composite-primary-ke).

Comment: Thanks.  I just got in touch with the data architect about this issue, and will probably result in some relational re-thinking.